# LWJGL 2.9.3, Unable to draw multiple VBO's per VAO

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'll get right into it, Below is a code dump of my class "RectManager" my issue is a strange opengl issue, I'm using lwjgl 2.9.3, and with my graphics card the vertext limit per VBO is 33000.

What my class does is simplify a group of squares into a series of rectangles, then buffer that data into a VBO and draw it on request.

Now the issue i'm having is I would group several instances of RectManager to draw many different meshes, however, if I don't supply a different VAO per instance of RectManager only the first instance will draw; and I have no idea why.
Any incite on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Remember, Both Examples have multiple instances of RectManager (6 to be exact).**

When I use the same VAO
[image]

When I use different VAO's
[image]

**Source**

```
protected class RectManager {
    Vector loopVec = new Vector(Chunk.chunkSize,Chunk.chunkSize,Chunk.chunkDepth);
    ArrayList<RecDim> rectArray = new ArrayList<RecDim>();

    int[] vboOffsets;
    int[] vboSizes;
    int vboSizeTotal = 0;
    int vboSizeReal = 0;
    int vboOffset = 0;
    int objectID;
    int bufferID;

    int indexX,indexY,indexZ;
    int bitwise = 0;
    int arrayID;

    boolean isStarted = false;
    int startC = 0;
    int startU = 0;
    int maxC = 1000;

    Direction dir;

    public RectManager(Direction depthDir,int arrID){
        dir = depthDir;

        Vector indexVec = new Vector(1,Chunk.chunkSize,Chunk.chunkSizeSq);

        if(depthDir.getPure() == Direction.NORTH){//Y+
            indexVec.rollRight();
            loopVec.rollRight();

            if(depthDir.isPure){
                bitwise = 2048;
            }else{
                bitwise = 1024;
            }
        }else if(depthDir.getPure() == Direction.EAST){//X+
            indexVec.rollLeft();
            loopVec.rollLeft();

            if(depthDir.isPure){
                bitwise = 4096;
            }else{
                bitwise = 8192;
            }
        }else{
            if(depthDir.isPure){
                bitwise = 32768;
            }else{
                bitwise = 16384;
            }
        }

        indexX = (int)indexVec.X;
        indexY = (int)indexVec.Y;
        indexZ = (int)indexVec.Z;

        vboOffsets = new int[(int)loopVec.Z];
        vboSizes = new int[(int)loopVec.Z];


        arrayID = arrID;
        objectID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        bufferID = GL15.glGenBuffers();

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(arrayID);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferID);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,Chunk.chunkSizeSq*6*Vertex.BYTES,GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);


        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,objectID);

        int defaultRectCount = 2000;
        vboSizeTotal = defaultRectCount*6*Vertex.BYTES+1;

        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vboSizeTotal,GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL11.GL_FLOAT,false,Vertex.BYTES,0);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(1,4,GL11.GL_FLOAT,false,Vertex.BYTES,Vertex.COLOR_OFFSET);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(2,2,GL11.GL_FLOAT,false,Vertex.BYTES,Vertex.UV_OFFSET);

        Vertex vert = new Vertex(0,0,0);
        int depth = 0;

        FloatBuffer buff = GL30.glMapBufferRange(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,vboSizeTotal,GL30.GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT,null).asFloatBuffer();

        Color c = new Color();
        c.setColorHSB((float)dir.ordinal()/6,1,1);
        vert.setColor(c.r,c.g,c.b);
        depth += (float)dir.ordinal()/6;

        for(int i=0; i<Chunk.chunkDepth; i++){
            vert.set(-0.5f,0.5f, 0.5f + depth).addToBuffer(buff);
            vert.set(-0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f + depth).addToBuffer(buff);
            vert.set(0.5f,0.5f, 0.5f + depth).addToBuffer(buff);


            vert.set(-0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f + depth).addToBuffer(buff);
            vert.set(0.5f,0.5f, 0.5f + depth).addToBuffer(buff);
            vert.set(0.5f,-0.5f, 0.5f + depth).addToBuffer(buff);
            depth++;
        }

        GL15.glUnmapBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void render(){
        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES,0,vboSizeReal/Vertex.BYTES);
    }

    private void updateVBO(int depth){
        int vboSize = vboSizes[depth]*Vertex.BYTES;
        int len = rectArray.size();
        int bytes = len*6*Vertex.BYTES;
        int offset = vboOffsets[depth];

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(arrayID);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,objectID);

        if(vboSize != bytes){
            //System.out.println("Pre "+vboSizeReal+","+vboSize+","+bytes);
            vboSizeReal = (vboSizeReal-vboSize)+bytes;
            vboSizes[depth] = len*6;

            //System.out.println("Resize! "+(vboSize-bytes)+" "+vboSize+" "+bytes+"\t\t"+vboSizeReal);


            if(vboSizeReal > vboSizeTotal){
                throw new RuntimeException("FUCK Out of Space VBO "+vboSizeReal+","+vboSizeTotal);
            }

            if(vboSize == 0){
                offset = vboOffset;
                vboOffsets[depth] = vboOffset;
                vboOffset += bytes;
            }else{
                int nextOffset = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                int oSet;
                int id = 0;
                int dif = vboSize-bytes;

                for(int i=0; i<vboOffsets.length; i++){
                    oSet = vboOffsets[i];

                    if(oSet < nextOffset && oSet > offset){
                        nextOffset = oSet;
                        id = i;
                    }
                }

                if(id == 0){//Shrink Buffer Instead
                    //vboOffset = offset+bytes;
                    vboOffset -= dif;//Its Positive
                }else{
                    int size = vboSizes[id]*Vertex.BYTES;

                    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL31.GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER,bufferID);

                    GL31.glCopyBufferSubData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,GL31.GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER,nextOffset,0,size);
                    GL31.glCopyBufferSubData(GL31.GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER,GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,offset+bytes,size);

                    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL31.GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER,0);

                    for(int i=0; i<vboOffsets.length; i++){
                        oSet = vboOffsets[i];

                        if(oSet > offset){
                            vboOffsets[i] = oSet-dif;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            vboSize = bytes;
        }else{
            //System.out.println("Non-Resize");
        }


        if(len == 0){
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
            GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
            return;
        }


        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL11.GL_FLOAT,false,Vertex.BYTES,0);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(1,4,GL11.GL_FLOAT,false,Vertex.BYTES,Vertex.COLOR_OFFSET);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(2,2,GL11.GL_FLOAT,false,Vertex.BYTES,Vertex.UV_OFFSET);

        FloatBuffer buff = GL30.glMapBufferRange(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,offset,vboSize,GL30.GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL30.GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT,null).asFloatBuffer();

        int sizeC,sizeU;
        Vertex vert = new Vertex(0,0,0);
        Color c = new Color();
        c.setColorHSB((float)depth/loopVec.Z,1,1);
        vert.setColor(c.r,c.g,c.b);
        //float count = 0;

        //System.out.println(dir+" "+(len > 0 ? rectArray.get(0) : "?")+" "+depth+" "+loopVec);
        Vector vec = new Vector();

        for(RecDim rect : rectArray){
            sizeC = rect.x2-rect.x;
            sizeU = rect.y2-rect.y;

            //c.setColorHSB(count++/(rectArray.size()+1),1,1);
            //vert.setColor(c.r,c.g,c.b);


            if(dir == Direction.UP){
                vert.set(-0.5f + rect.x,0.5f + rect.y2, 0.5f + depth).setUV(0,0).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(-0.5f + rect.x,-0.5f + rect.y, 0.5f + depth).setUV(0,sizeU).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(0.5f + rect.x2,0.5f + rect.y2, 0.5f + depth).setUV(sizeC,0).addToBuffer(buff);

                vert.set(0.5f + rect.x2,0.5f + rect.y2, 0.5f + depth).setUV(sizeC,0).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(-0.5f + rect.x,-0.5f + rect.y, 0.5f + depth).setUV(0,sizeU).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(0.5f + rect.x2,-0.5f + rect.y, 0.5f + depth).setUV(sizeC,sizeU).addToBuffer(buff);
            }else if(dir == Direction.DOWN){
                vert.set(0.5f + rect.x2,0.5f + rect.y2,-0.5f + depth).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(0.5f + rect.x2,-0.5f + rect.y,-0.5f + depth).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(-0.5f + rect.x,0.5f + rect.y2,-0.5f + depth).addToBuffer(buff);

                vert.set(-0.5f + rect.x,0.5f + rect.y2,-0.5f + depth).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(0.5f + rect.x2,-0.5f + rect.y,-0.5f + depth).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(-0.5f + rect.x,-0.5f + rect.y,-0.5f + depth).addToBuffer(buff);
            }else if(dir == Direction.EAST){
                vert.set(0.5f + depth,-0.5f + rect.x,0.5f + rect.y2).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(0.5f + depth,0.5f + rect.x2,-0.5f + rect.y).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(0.5f + depth,0.5f + rect.x2,0.5f + rect.y2).addToBuffer(buff);

                vert.set(0.5f + depth,-0.5f + rect.x,-0.5f + rect.y).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(0.5f + depth,0.5f + rect.x2,-0.5f + rect.y).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(0.5f + depth,-0.5f + rect.x,0.5f + rect.y2).addToBuffer(buff);
            }else if(dir == Direction.WEST){
                vert.set(-0.5f + depth,0.5f + rect.x2,0.5f + rect.y2).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(-0.5f + depth,0.5f + rect.x2,-0.5f + rect.y).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(-0.5f + depth,-0.5f + rect.x,0.5f + rect.y2).addToBuffer(buff);

                vert.set(-0.5f + depth,-0.5f + rect.x,0.5f + rect.y2).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(-0.5f + depth,0.5f + rect.x2,-0.5f + rect.y).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(-0.5f + depth,-0.5f + rect.x,-0.5f + rect.y).addToBuffer(buff);
            }else if(dir == Direction.NORTH){
                vert.set(0.5f + rect.y2,0.5f + depth,0.5f + rect.x2).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(0.5f + rect.y2,0.5f + depth,-0.5f + rect.x).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(-0.5f + rect.y,0.5f + depth,0.5f + rect.x2).addToBuffer(buff);

                vert.set(-0.5f + rect.y,0.5f + depth,0.5f + rect.x2).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(0.5f + rect.y2,0.5f + depth,-0.5f + rect.x).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(-0.5f + rect.y,0.5f + depth,-0.5f + rect.x).addToBuffer(buff);

            }else{//SOUTH
                vert.set(-0.5f + rect.y,-0.5f + depth,0.5f + rect.x2).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(0.5f + rect.y2,-0.5f + depth,-0.5f + rect.x).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(0.5f + rect.y2,-0.5f + depth,0.5f + rect.x2).addToBuffer(buff);

                vert.set(-0.5f + rect.y,-0.5f + depth,-0.5f + rect.x).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(0.5f + rect.y2,-0.5f + depth,-0.5f + rect.x).addToBuffer(buff);
                vert.set(-0.5f + rect.y,-0.5f + depth,0.5f + rect.x2).addToBuffer(buff);

            }
        }

        GL15.glUnmapBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void calcAll(){
        for(int d=0; d<loopVec.Z; d++){
            isStarted = false;
            maxC = 1000;

            calcLayerInternal(d);

            if(isStarted){
                rectArray.add(new RecDim(startC,startU,maxC,(int)loopVec.Y-1));

                d--;
                continue;
            }

            updateVBO(d);
            rectArray.clear();
        }

        rectArray.clear();
    }

    public void calcLayer(int d){
        rectArray.clear();

        while(true) {
            isStarted = false;
            maxC = 1000;

            calcLayerInternal(d);

            if(!isStarted){
                break;
            }

            rectArray.add(new RecDim(startC,startU,maxC,(int)loopVec.Y-1));
        }

        updateVBO(d);

    }

    private void calcLayerInternal(int d){
        int index;
        Block b;

        for(int u=0; u<loopVec.Y; u++){
            for(int c=0; c<loopVec.X; c++){
                if(isStarted){
                    if(c > maxC){
                        break;
                    }

                    if(c < startC){
                        c = startC;
                    }
                }else if(inRect(c,u,rectArray)){
                    continue;
                }


                index = d*indexZ + u*indexY + c*indexX;
                b = Blocks.getBlockByID(owner.blocks[index]);

                if(b.isAir() || inRect(c,u,rectArray) || (owner.metaData[index] & bitwise) == 0){
                    if(isStarted){
                        if(maxC != 1000){
                            rectArray.add(new RecDim(startC,startU,maxC,u-1));
                            u = 0;

                            isStarted = false;
                            maxC = 1000;

                            break;
                        }else{
                            maxC = c-1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }else if(!isStarted){
                    isStarted = true;
                    startC = c;
                    startU = u;
                }
            }

            if(isStarted && maxC == 1000){
                maxC = (int)loopVec.X-1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

```
public class Vertex {
    public static int SIZE = 9;
    public static int BYTES = Float.BYTES * 9;
    public static int POSITION_OFFSET = 0;
    public static int COLOR_OFFSET =  Float.BYTES * 3;
    public static int UV_OFFSET = Float.BYTES * 7;

    float[] data = new float[SIZE];

    protected Vertex(float X,float Y,float Z){
        data[0] = X;
        data[1] = Y;
        data[2] = Z;
        data[3] = 1f;
        data[4] = 1f;
        data[5] = 1f;
        data[6] = 1f;
        data[7] = 0;
        data[8] = 0;
    }

    public static Vertex createVertex(float X,float Y,float Z){
        return new Vertex(X,Y,Z);
    }

    public static FloatBuffer toBuffer(Vertex[] vertices,FloatBuffer buf){
        if(buf == null){
            buf = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length * SIZE);
        }
        //FloatBuffer ret = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length * SIZE);

        for(Vertex v : vertices){
            buf.put(v.data);
        }

        buf.flip();

        return buf;
    }

    public static FloatBuffer toBuffer(Vertex[] vertices){
        return toBuffer(vertices,null);
    }

    public Vertex addToBuffer(FloatBuffer buf){
        buf.put(data);

        return this;
    }

    public Vertex set(float X,float Y,float Z){
        data[0] = X;
        data[1] = Y;
        data[2] = Z;

        return this;
    }

    public float getX(){
        return data[0];
    }

    public float getY(){
        return data[1];
    }

    public float getZ(){
        return data[2];
    }

    public Vertex setX(float X){
        data[0] = X;

        return this;
    }

    public Vertex setY(float Y){
        data[1] = Y;

        return this;
    }

    public Vertex setZ(float Z){
        data[2] = Z;

        return this;
    }

    public Vertex setColor(float R,float G,float B,float A){
        data[3] = R;
        data[4] = G;
        data[5] = B;
        data[6] = A;

        return this;
    }

    public Vertex setColor(float R,float G,float B){
        return setColor(R,G,B,1f);
    }

    public Vertex setUV(float U,float V){
        data[7] = U;
        data[8] = V;

        return this;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

objectID is the ID associated with my VBO.
I'm doing some dinky memory management to and I need to shift a good amount of memory around to do so. The best idea I had was to load all the data I need to shift onto a buffer (bufferID) then copy from the buffer back onto the VBO. The geometry is being loaded inside of the "updateVBO" method in a for loop.

**Edit 3, to clarify**

The idea is to separate multiple "layers" of terrain, but to keep it all inside of one VBO.
So first, I allocate the the VBO, then as the terrain is manipulated I "recalculate" each "layer" that was affected.
Each "layer" of terrain is allocated an amount of space in the VBO.
When pieces of terrain are added or removed from a "layer" the size of that "layer" is changed according, meaning that all other layers in the VBO need to have their offsets changed.
In order to "shift" the actual data in the VBO the only thing I can do is "copy" the data that needs to be shifted from my VBO into the Buffer, Then "copy" the data from the Buffer back into the VBO with the correct offset.

Comment: Is `Vertex` an LWJGL class? If not, could you provide the source code for it?

Comment: I just added the vertex class, however its really just to interleaf the data.

Comment: What's `bufferID` and `objectID`? Where is your geometry?

Comment: I added more information.

Comment: It's not really clear for me, can you elaborate it further?

Comment: I hope that helps clear things up, the reason for doing all this strange memory manipulation is because terrain manipulation does not happen very often, So i'm doing my best to optimize rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that when I'm binding all of the RectManagers to the same VAO even though they all have different buffer objects they seem to either share or overlap the same memory region...

I'll report back and update this answer with more information soonish.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that given the amount of geometry we are talking about (that is absolutely low), you could use a different vao for each layer. However, you should always profile to know if it is worth or not.

Said that, if you want to load every layer inside a single vbo, you can do it. And if you want do it right, you should use `glCopyBufferSubData` as you are already doing.

Anyway, you should be aware that both `objectID` and `bufferID` refer exactly to the same type, that is buffers or vertex buffer objects. They are *not* different objects.

This means when a layer changes what you should do is allocate a new vbo with the right size and transfer directly all the valid layers inside it and then use that. No other copies needed.

One thing that can be source of trouble is that when you use `glCopyBufferSubData` you should make clear what is the source and destination buffers, like [here](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_320/buffer/Gl_320_buffer_update.java#L162) for example.

Double check what is still bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` when you call `glCopyBufferSubData`. You may want to use `GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER` to get first things working and then try to switch to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the response; What I'm confused about is if I never reallocate the main buffer (objectID) and that if I only mapped sections of it, then all the data would persist. Another bumer is with ~3000 vertexs per chunk and rendering 16 chunks i'm down to 300fps... not really sure how to increase that... I've got to bind the array and object for each chunk, then only call one drawArray, so i dunno.

Comment: Yep, using a totaly different method, and reallocating the VBO EVERY TIME data is changed it works fantastic... until they all use the same arrayID.